# JSP Pagetemplate layout

Tags: java, css, jsp, servlets

I noticed that on JSF pages i can include templates in my xhtml page like

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/tmp/tmp.xhtml">
```

is there any alternative to this using JSP Pages+ Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

With plain JSP you can only [reuse content](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnajb.html) with instructions like:

```
<%@ include file="banner.jspf" %>
```

JSF facelets allow passing parameters to the [facelet](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqxp.html) to do this with JSP you would need an additional framework like [struts](https://struts.apache.org/).

Comment: extension for jsp-fragment which does only represent a fragment of a page like a header, footer or menu etc.